# Integrating Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am following [this](http://javatechig.com/android/share-file-to-dropbox-in-android-example)
tutorial and trying to integrate dropbox in my Android app. But after clicking login button it showing `The URL is not valid | Are you sure your app secret is correct?` But I have checked my app key and app secret in another app and its working.
Am I missing something  here?

I have changed app key in both Main activity and manifest file and imported all library also.

Comment: Are you using your own app secret key or the one mentioned in the tutorial ?

Comment: @San My own app secret key

Comment: Try printing it first so as to be sure !! Clean the project once and try again.. I'll dig more and get back to ya....

Comment: You can also try ShareActionProvider but it brings about all the sharing apps from your mobile.

Comment: @San I cleaned my project and checked app secret key again . But still no luck

Comment: I am using the Dropbox Sync API with no problems, if it covers your needs you could consider trying that instead.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I tried Dropbox Sync API also and tried to run its sample programs, but it showing force close. I think Dropbox Sync API can only access file type and app type. So I gave only datastore permission to my app.

Comment: What do you mean by file type and app type? The only limit I encountered was the folder restriction, that is, Dropbox Sync API can only access the app folder in Dropbox. Oh, and by the way, sometimes I have had to download and install the Dropbox app from Google Play and login to the account I wanted to access.. maybe your problem is related to that.

Comment: It sounds like Kunu is referring to the "app folder" and "file type" permissions. The Sync API currently only supports these two permissions (and not "full Dropbox"). The different permissions are detailed here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions

Comment: Regarding the issue itself, make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK. If you're still having trouble, Dropbox Developer support would be the right place to go for help: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: We actually tracked this down to a bug in the SDK when using OAuth 1. We recommend switching to OAuth 2 anyway, but the bug should be fixed in the updated version here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android

Comment: @Greg Thanks, I will try this SDK and let you know .